# Facebook comment in asp.net with dynamic urls

Tags: asp.net, html, facebook

I am creating facebook comment box,it works fine with the static urls, but my url contains the query string parameters with it like this: http://bugnull.com/article_content.aspx?id=19&title=code+testing.

I want to have the different comments for each unique url.

Here is the code I am using :

Code just after the body tag:

```
   <div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>    (function (d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=XXXXXXXXXXX";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    } (document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

  **and code for the comment box:**


<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://bugnull.com/article_content.aspx?id=(.*)&title=(.*)" data-num-posts="2" data-width="500"></div>
```

Here I want to change the url such that the above url is manipulated such that it allows me to have unique comment thread for each unique page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution which was quite fascinating,here is the manipulation in the code required:

In the div tag :

```
<div id="fbdiv" runat="server "class="fb-comments" data-href="http://bugnull.com/article_content.aspx?id=(.*)&title=(.*)" data-num-posts="2" data-width="500"></div>
```

I included runat="server" and in aspx.cs it was accessible:

```
fbdiv.Attributes["data-href"]="xyz.com?title="+Request.QueryString["title"];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply have this in your javascript code (in case you're using jQuery)

```
$("#fbdiv").attr("data-href", document.location.href);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
        <div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://www.zajelcard.com/<%=Request.QueryString("pagename")%>" data-numposts="5"></div>
```